# VLC shows two windows for one video

Tags: mac, video, vlc-media-player

I've updated my VLC Player on the Mac and now I have two windows for one video. How can I disable this, so it works the old way?
[image]

Comment: Amazing how any given solution below is not entirely fixing the actual issue, still in 2022.

Answer (score 28):

Tried all of the answers above, nothing worked
BUT this did on *Ubuntu 22.04*:

> switch Tools > Preferences > Video > Output to "X11 video output"

[solution screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtnEC.png)

source: last answer of https://www.linux.org/threads/opening-a-video-file-with-vlc-opens-two-seprate-windwos-screenshot-included.34753/

Comment: Also worked on Fedora 36

Comment: Worked on Debian testing

Comment: Works for me in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. Finally.

Answer (score 15):

In **Preferences -> Interface**, check **Allow only one Instance**

Comment: This is unrelated - it *is* only one instance of VLC. It just has two windows. @heavyd's answer is the right one.

Comment: This problem still happens even with "Allow only one instance" enabled.

Answer (score 7):

In the VLC preferences under the *Interface* section check the box for *Integrate video in interface* (In older versions this option was labeled *Embed video in interface*)

Comment: For me it was already checked, but unchecking it and checking it again fixed the issue. Must be some preferences bug.

Comment: I can't find this checkbox in the latest version of VLC.

Comment: @AaronFranke looks like the option has changed to "Integrate video in interface"

Answer (score 5):

For me, setting "`Number of clones`" = 1 fixed this exact issue

Tools > Preferences > All > Video Splitters > Clone > Number of clones = 1

Comment: This is the only thing that worked! Thank you for this.

Answer (score 3):

In the VLC preferences under the audio tab make sure visualization is set to default.
This solved my problem of the visualizer window appearing on top of the video window.

Answer (score 2):

Great answers but none of these worked for me.
Must be a bug. Doesnt behave rationally.

1. View -> Docked playlist [x]
2. View -> Playlist (playlist is now visible)
   -> Press Stop, to stop the video
   -> Double click the item in your playlist, so the video will start
3. View -> Playlist (playlist is now hidden and video is inside VLC main interface.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this would help anyone, but since it worked for me, I share it here:

```
Tools > Preferences > Video > Display
```

> Disable the "Window decorations" check box

P.S: I only tested this on Linux (Debian testing with Gnome and X11).

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

In case it might help someone else. I'm running ubuntu 22 and most of the times the video would open in a separate window, rarely it would work as intended.

What solved it is under tools > preferences > interface: check 'Integrate video in interface' but remove the check on 'Resize interface to video size'.

I had tried all the solutions in this thread but none were working, this seems to have solved it.

Answer (score 1):

tools > preferences > interface: UNcheck 'Integrate video in interface'

then closing the app reopening and (checking again)

tools > preferences > interface: check 'Integrate video in interface' again

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

When you upgrade, under the **Preferences > Interface** tab, you should see an option **Show video within the main window**. It should be checked.

*If you still have multiple windows, the VLC download package has a separate app under the **Goodies** folder called **Delete VLC Preferences.app**. Run that and try again.*

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of split video windows, under preferences, (show all), video, splitters, deselect split modes! (OSX High Sierra)

Answer (score 0):

open VLC and press on **"Ctrl + P"** > **Interface**, check the box **Allow only one Instance**

Comment: exact copy/paste of [previous answer](https://superuser.com/a/1567272/763386)